# OpenCV: Matrix multiplication with a matrix containing Vec3d and a matrix containing doubles

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am using *OpenCV* for some time and now I hit the point where I need a multiplication of this type:

> Define a matrix `T`, which contains elements of the type `Vec3d`<sup>1</sup>  . Matrix `T` has the size: M X N. Matrix `T` has to be multiplied with a Vector `Phi`, which has the size: N X 1, containing `double`s as values. Each element of the result has to be the result of a matrix multiplication of both matrices.

I don't want to do a component-wise multiplication, but a "real" matrix multiplication, e.g. multiplying the first element of `T`<sup>2</sup> with the first element of matrix `J`, then multiplying the second element of matrix `T`<sup>3</sup> with the second element of matrix `J`. Do this until you completed the first row of `T` and then sum up the results. The result is a M X 1.

For example, if `T` would be a 3 X 2 matrix and `Phi` a 2 X 1 matrix, then the calculation should be `T_11 * phi_11 + T_12 * phi_21` for the first value of the result. Currently I'm using two for loops which are slow:

```
for (int i = 0; i<M; ++i){
    cv::Mat summedResult = cv::Mat(3, 1, CV_64F, double(0));
    for (uint32 j = 0; j<N; ++j){
        summedResult = summedResult + 
        (cv::Mat(mMatrixT.at<cv::Vec3d>(i, j)) * mMatrixPhi.at<double>(j));
    }
    // The result matrix contains values of type Vec3d again
    mResultMatrix.at<cv::Vec3d>(i) = cv::Vec3d(summedResult);
}
```

More generally: Is it possible to efficiently multiply matrices containing `Vec3ds` and `double`s in OpenCV?

---

<sup>1. three dimensional vector containing doubles.</sup>

<sup>2. coordinate: 1,1</sup>

<sup>3. coordinate: 1,2</sup>

Comment: Don't try to "help" the compiler, `mMatrixT.at(i, j)` is just fine (i.e., do not explicitly give the template parameter if it has already been deduced)

Comment: Your matrix T seems to have the size MxNx3. Then you want to multiply this T with the *vector* phi of size Nx1. But in the next sentence you state that there is a matrix matrix multiplication involved. But there are no two matrices. (Except matrix J which appears out of nowhere) Please elaborate. Btw "real" matrix multiplication involving two 2D matrices with fitting dimensions can be done simply by using `A * B`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to reduce a lot of allocations, but it still does not hit a suitable performance. A good improvement though :).

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl You're right, I was mixing matrix J and Phi. In this case matrix J and matrix Phi are both the same. I know that two matrices containing double values can be simply multiplied using the star operator. Now I have a matrix T containing vec3d values and a matrix Phi which contains regular double values. Now I want to multiply the vectors from T with the scalar values from Phi, so that the resulting vectors from each multiplication sum up with each row of matrix T. Sorry for confusing you mixing up matrices.

Comment: what should be the result? what's the matrix multiplication of a 1xn matrix of Vec3d with a nx1 matrix of type double? should that be the sum of double_i * Vec3d_i? I don't think you can use matrix multiplication directly there because 3-channeled matrices aren't defined mathematically for matrix multiplication with single channel matrices.

Comment: @Kosch you can convert Vec3d mat to a mat with 3 times the column number (single channel double elements then) and convert your double matrix to a double matrix of triple size (repeating values before using next value). Then a matrix product should be the desired result, but I doubt it will be much faster ;)

Comment: ah no, that doesn't work since you'll get a single value instead of a Vec3d for each matrix element... sorry

Comment: what are typical values for `M` and `N`? and how much does it take to you?

Comment: M can reach a size between 1000 and 8000, while N will not exceed a size of 33.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what kind of result you expect, but maybe try this:

Assuming that you have a MxN matrix of Vec3d and a Nx1 Matrix of type double, your result will be a Mx1 matrix of type Vec3d:

```
for (int i = 0; i<M; ++i)
    {
        cv::Vec3d summedResult; // here this must be a Vec3d instead of a matrix, if I assume the right result expection
        for (uint32 j = 0; j<N; ++j)
        {
            summedResult = summedResult + (mMatrixT.at<cv::Vec3d>(i, j) * mMatrixPhi.at<double>(j));
        }
        // The result matrix contains values of type Vec3d again
        mResultMatrix.at<cv::Vec3d>(i) = summedResult;
    }
```

EDIT:

ah sorry, didnt read to the end that your provided code works but is too slow... well, I expect that there is no optimization for that because mathematically this isnt defined. What you can do is to convert your Vec3d mat to a Mx(3*N) matrix and convert your Nx1 mat to a (3*N)x1 mat (3 times the same value before the next value) and use the OpenCV matrix product directly. But probably that's not faster because of the 3* bigger size of both matrices ;)

EDIT: will be a different result, since each element will be the sum of the Vec3d elements...

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try :).

Comment: @ThomasKosch This is my guess as well, maybe you can refactor your calculations to use mathematically (well)defined calculations. Otherwise you might try to use a 3D matrix instead of a 2D matrix of vectors. Arrange your matrix dimensions such that you access contiguous memory when doing dot products or matrix products.

Comment: @Micka Same as for OP: Don't help the compiler, let it deduce the template parameters where possible.